# ORM Inheritance and Decorator Support (Hibernate?)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

At work I've been using our in house ORM (pre 2000) and we're looking at moving to another ORM solution for our java, however there are some specific requirements. Does anyone know any form or ORM that supports these requests?

1. Support for inheritance: In our java we have quite a deep inheritance structure and currently if I add an attribute to a class at the "top" then I have to manually edit the ORM procedure (in SQL) to add the new class for each of the sub classes
2. Support for decorator tables: A few of our classes need to be able to store any (user provided) attribute against a particular object, currently this is just a table that matches Item Id to a row containing FieldName and FieldValue and we pull all of these in as attributes. See below for a better explanation.
3. Object persistence inbuilt, so objects are only loaded and written to/from the database when requested and otherwise are left in memory. Would also be great if any changes could be automatically saved when you finish, rather than having to call `.save()` (though potentially dangerous?)
4. As usual, easy to use (preferably - isn't this what we all want?) and good performance

Thanks for your time, happy to update the question with what we chose and why and some hints we discover while implementing!

---

**Further explanation of #2:**

*(please don't ask why it has to be like this, changing it is "out of scope" of this project)*

Item table:

```
ItemId | Type  | Price
-------|-------|-------
1      | Mouse | 9.99
2      | Dog   | 12.99
```

Decorator table:

```
ItemId | FieldName | Value
-------|-----------|-------
1      | Age       | 12
2      | Breed     | Blue Long Hair
2      | Name      | Fluffy
```

Item Objects:

```
Item1
  ItemId -> 1
  Type -> Mouse
  Price -> 9.99
  Age -> 12

Item2
  ItemId -> 2
  Type -> Dog
  Price -> 12.99
  Breed -> Blue Long Hair
  Name -> Fluffy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JPA (and thus Hibernate) support inheritance.
2. I don't quite understand what you mean
3. JPA/Hibernate, by default, leave objects in memory for the duration of a transaction. Each transaction has its own copy of the object, and this first-level cache is recreated at the beginning of each transaction, since any other concurrent transaction (or even another application) could have modified the object. There is no destructor in Java, so I don't understand what you mean. But at the end of the transaction, by default, every change to an entity is automatically saved to the database.
4. If you read the documentation and takes the time to understand how it works, then JPA/Hibernate is relatively easy to use. But it has it learning curve. The performance is OK in 95% of the typical use cases, as long as you understand what the ORM does behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Re 2. we have a class "item" that can have any number of attributes (provided by the user) we need a database side way (because that's how it currently works and can't be changes) to accept any field on this item. E.g. it only has name and price defined, but for one item I could add color

Comment: Have added further info above

Comment: What are the types of Object1 and Object2? What do these types have in common? Mapping the DB structure above with JPA would need an Item entity, with a OneToMany association with an ItemField entity. The ItemField entity would have a name field and a value field.

Comment: They'd need to be an "Item" in java and have the method `.get/setAge()` for Item1 and `.get/setName()` and -> `get/setBreed()` for Item2

Comment: So Item2 and Item1 are subclasses of Item, and contain additional fields that should be stored in the decorator table, right? This is not supported by JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Well kind of, Item1 and Item2 are instances of Item with additional fields, I get this goes against OO but it's the way the implemented it in the past :-(

Comment: That's not even possible in Java. A class has a well-defined set of fields, and you can't have additional fields in instances of this class. So I still don't understand what you mean. Why don't you show us the source code?

Comment: Well that's what I thought, currently we manually have to add attributes all over the place whenever a user wants one. I guess I'd have to change it so it was something like `.getDecoratorAttribute("name")` and `.setDecoratorAttribute("age", 12)` is this possible with conventional ORM?

Comment: That's what I suggested in a previous comment: have a OneToMany between Item and ItemField. The above methods would get/set values in the collection of ItemField instances.